# How can I skip certificate validation with a Fetch API request within the browser?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have the following code running in the **browser**:

```
  const response = await fetch(`${url}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${authorization}`,
    },
    body: loginData,
  })
```

when I call this, I get the following response back from the server:

```
<URL> net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

I control the server and it is using a self-signed certificate.

In my fetch request, I want to ignore or skip the certificate validation.

I have tried:

```
  const response = await fetch(`${url}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${authorization}`,
    },
    body: loginData,
    agent: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  })
```

but the behavior remains the same.

How can I skip the validation?

Comment: Well obviously a script in a website cannot just decide on its own to ignore certificate errors. There are only two possibilities: 1. Use a certificate that is signed by a trusted certificate authority (for instance let's encrypt) or 2. Add your certificate to your browser's or OS's trusted certificates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is blocking the request, it has nothing to do with your code snippet. You need to add an exception for your cert.

Chrome: https://superuser.com/a/41937

Firefox: https://superuser.com/a/41937